# SOAP XML message Signing in python

Tags: python, ssl, xml-signature

Are there any soap message signing libraries present in Python 2.7.5 ?
I found a following library that does the following function :

```
from signxml import xmldsig    
cert = open("example.pem").read()
key = open("example.key").read()
root = ElementTree.fromstring(signature_data)
xmldsig(root).sign(key=key, cert=cert)
verified_data = xmldsig(root).verify()
```

But it needs signxml  to be installed seperatly . Unfortunately I do not have the permission to install packages on the server ,  Is there an existing library in python 2.7.5 that I can use to achieve this task ?